# What pattern to use for the following scenario?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have the following class:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(string name) {
        agg = new Aggregate(name);
    }
private:
    Aggregate* agg;
};
```

Now I need to extend this class:

```
class Derived : Base {
public:
    Derived(string name) : Base(name) {
        agg2 = new Aggregate2(name);
    }
private:
    Aggregate2* agg2;
};
```

What I want is when I create a `Base` object, `Aggregate` needs to be created and when I create a `Derived` object only `Aggregate2` should be created.

Now this is not happening because `Aggregate` its created inside the constructor which is called when I create a `Derived` object and like this `Aggregate` and `Aggregate2` would be created.

I could move the creation to a different method and call that after creating the object.
Is there any other elegant way to do what I want ?

Comment: Why not create a separate, no-op constructor that's `protected`?

Comment: So, when you create `Derived` you want to leave `agg` uninitialized? You can do that, for example using Rufflewind's suggestion, but it sounds like you are trying to break the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) to me which is generally a bad idea.

Comment: [OT]: You should use `std::unique_ptr<Aggregate> agg;` instead of raw owning pointer.

Comment: My first thought was, you should make a Base template instead and make Derived inherit from Base<Aggregate2>, but to be honest I would reconsider the class hierarchy. Right now your class hierarchy expresses that Derived is a Base, which, from your description, it isn't really. I agree with Chris Drew, that this is a bad idea. Do you have any reason not to go for a template right away?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
class Base {
public:
    explicit Base(string name) : agg(new Aggregate(name)) {}
protected:
    Base() = default;
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Aggregate> agg;
};

class Derived : Base {
public:
    // implicit call to Base(), you may be explicit if you want
    Derived(string name) : agg2(new Aggregate2(name)) {}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Aggregate2> agg2;
};
```

Comment: This does what OP wants, so +1. But if it is not OK to create a `Base` with an uninitialized `agg`. I don't see why it should be OK to create something derived from `Base` with an uninitialized `agg` either.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: `agg` is default initialized with `nullptr` value.

Comment: True, I like the suggestion to use `unique_ptr` and this is one of the benefits. But the fact remains that you couldn't create the original `Base` without it having a non-null `Aggregate`. With your suggestion you can, so some of the original behaviour of `Base` could be broken.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: uninitialized memory may also be `nullptr`. If really OP wants to use raw pointer, so I would be sure that default Base constructor zero initialize the pointer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you shouldn't do. If your second class isn't supposed to have the first Aggregate member, then the right way is to make two separate classes and **not** to use inheritance:

```
class Foo1 { ... };
class Foo2 { ... };
```

Now if you **really** have a reason to use inheritance you have a few options:
- Use a base class from which both Foo1 and Foo2 will derive. The base class only contains what is common to both Foo1 and Foo2. The Aggregates you need go separately into Foo1 and Foo2. (**recommended**)
- Let Foo1 have a union member (if you know the whys and wherefores of unions):

```
union Bla { std::unique_ptr<Agg1> a1; std::unique_ptr<Agg2> a2; };
```

And I should strongly emphasize that I can hardly think of an example where the second version is meaningful... Go for a separate base class!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() { }
    Base(string name) {
        agg = new Aggregate(name);
    }
    void setName(string name) {
       agg = new Aggregate(name);
    }
private:
    Aggregate* agg;
};

class Derived : Base {
public:
    Derived(string name) {
        agg2 = new Aggregate2(name);
    }
private:
    Aggregate2* agg2;
};
```

Comment: This works . But default construction of Base() is allowed and that'll leave Aggregate in Base class unconstructed.

Comment: @Jagannath Yes, the default `Base` constructor should be `protected`. And some explanation text would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a string type data member in Base class; which can be assigned value (same as name,in constructor) and you can access it in derived also(make it protected) to initialize agg2 in Derived  class.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a constructor overload for this:

```
class Base {
    public:
        Base(string name) : agg(new Aggregate(name)) {}
    protected:
        Base(Aggregate* agg) : agg(agg) {}    //Base will take possession of the passed pointer.
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Aggregate> agg;
};

class Derived : Base {
    public:
        Derived(string name) : Base(new Aggregate2(name)) {}
};
```

---

Note:
This assumes that `Aggregate2` is derived from `Aggregate`. This assumption is based on the fact that removing ability of a base class in a derived class is at least a very strong code smell. So I concluded that both aggregates basically serve the same function, so that the second variable to hold the `Aggregate2` instance is superfluous, and that `Aggregate2` is a subclass of `Aggregate` to match behavior with relation.

Comment: This assumes `Aggregate2` is derived from `Aggregate`.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Right. I added a note explaining my leap of conclusion.

Comment: That is correct, I forgot to mention that Aggregate2 is derrived from Aggregate